# How to simplify an equation of the $(x^2 + y^2)^{1/2}$ For example:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am studying an Engineering Mathematics (Stroud) book and two of the questions are giving me a hard time.

1st)

$$(x^2 - 1)^2 \frac{(x + 1)^{1/2}}{(x - 1)^{3/2}}$$

The book says the answer is: $$(x + 1)^2 (x^2 - 1)^{1/2}$$

2nd)
$$(x^2 - y^2)^{1/2}(x - y)^{3/2}(x + y)^{-1/2}$$

I have tried to solve these but all the result I end up with are just different forms of the the same equation. I entered them into wolfram it also gives the same answer that I have always been getting. The two questions are similar but I don't understand how does one go about simplifying the above expressions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1^{st})$
$$(x^2 - 1)^2 \frac{(x + 1)^{1/2}}{(x - 1)^{3/2}}$$
$$\implies ((x+1)(x-1))^2\frac{(x + 1)^{1/2}}{(x - 1)^{3/2}}$$
$$\implies (x+1)^{2+1/2}(x-1)^{2-3/2}  $$
$$\implies (x+1)^2(x+1)^{1/2}(x-1)^{1/2}  $$
$$\implies (x+1)^2((x+1)(x-1))^{1/2}  $$
$$\implies (x+1)^2(x^2-1)^{1/2}  $$

$2^{nd})$
$$(x^2 - y^2)^{1/2}(x - y)^{3/2}(x + y)^{-1/2}$$
$$\implies ((x+y)(x-y))^{1/2}(x-y)^{3/2}(x+y)^{-1/2}$$
$$\implies (x+y)^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}}(x-y)^{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{2}}$$
$$\implies (x+y)^{0}(x-y)^{2}$$
$$\implies (x-y)^{2}$$

Comment: @WalidBeydoun : sure, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use that $(x^2-y^2) = (x-y)(x+y)$
Also use it when $y=1$ in particular.
The rest is trivial expression manipulation.

Comment: Yeah I guess, don't know why that rule slipped my mind. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for 1st problem**

$x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$

Then we have, $(x+1)^2(x-1)^2\cdot\frac{(x+1)^{1/2}}{(x-1)^{3/2}}=(x+1)^2(x-1)^{2-{3/2}}=(x+1)^2(x-1)^{1/2}(x+1)^{1/2}$